# Why is RSpec unable to location the models I've just created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, automated-tests, factory-bot

When I run rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb to test, I got this error:

```
 /home/alex/dev/greenbull/spec/models/user_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>':
 uninitialized constant User (NameError)
```

Here's the /spec folder structure

```
|-models
| |_
|   |-task.rb
|   |-user.rb
|   |-task_spec.rb
|   |-user_spec.rb
|
|-factories
| |_
|   |-tasks.rb
|   |-users.rb
|
|-spec_helper.rb
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'factory_girl'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

**spec/models/user.rb**

```
class User
end
```

Why is this so? Wham am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are not supposed to have models in your spec folder

Comment: So where are they supposed to be located?

Comment: they are supposed to be defined in your app

Comment: They are in app/models folder.

Comment: then what is your `user.rb` in your spec folder?

Comment: @apneadiving: should be `spec/models/user_spec.rb`, btw :)

Comment: @apneadiving If I delete spec/models/user.rb nothing changes. Still same error. It looks like Rspec can't see the models

Comment: I feel like you lack `require 'rspec/rails'` no?

Comment: @apneadiving Included the above line in spec_helper and now it says - `<class:ERB>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Template::Handlers::ERB::ENCODING_FLAG (NameError)

Comment: so you have another issue now

Comment: @apneadiving Thanks for helping

Comment: @apneadiving I resolved my issue. There is a hidden file in the app root folder named .rspec and I specified `--require rails_helper` in here.

Answer (score 1):

The spec file shouldn't look like that, it would be something like this

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  describe 'my spec' do
    it 'works' do
      expect(true).to eq true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden file in the app root folder named .rspec and I specified `--require rails_helper` in here